# Power transmission in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

lets say you have a battery and a resistance which form a circuit. The electrons flow through the resistance.

How can you visualize the flow of energy?
How do you visualize the energy field?

I don't understand how the energy from the battery comes to the resistance,
because it is not transported directly by the electrons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the energy in a circuit flows OUTSIDE the circuit as electromagnetic fields surrounding the wires. Better people than I have produced some pretty diagrams to help visualize this. See:

- "[In a Simple Circuit, Where does the Energy Flow?](http://amasci.com/elect/poynt/poynt.html)"
- "Energy Transfer in Electrical Circuits" ([PDF](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/teaching/phys208/lectures/poynting_vector.pdf))
- "Understanding Electricity and Circuits" ([PDF](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/teach/module_home/px263/lectures/sefton.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

The battery generates an electric field across the circuit, you can visualize a field as force lines. This is because the two ends of the battery are at differnt energies. If you have electrons that can move freely in response to an electric field (the electric fiels makes force on the electrons), such as in a conductor, then the electrons will move around.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about an energy field.

However, I see two things.

First, what causes the energy transfer : the two terminals of the battery have different potential. This means that the electrons will try to go from the - to the +. If they are allowed to do so (if there is a wire), the difference of potential tends to decrases, and the chemical reaction of the battery takes place to overcome the lack of charges. The resistance of the wire makes the electron flow difficult : they give a part of their (kinetic) energy to the wire when they collide with atoms (it is **really** a big simplication), the same way that you have difficulties to run if the wind is strong.

Second, there are some real (I mean serious and efficient) ways to model and understand energy transfers, for example the [bond graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_graph).