# Power transmission loss in a large circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

This is a followup question to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149194/power-transmission-in-a-circuit)

Consider a large circuit like the german electric power transmission network.
You have a lot of of people consuming power and a lot of power stations producing energy. All of them are spaced at different places all over Germany.

Someone told me following: When there is a local demand somewhere then it is better to increase the power of a local power station, because the loss of energy for transmission is lower.

But i can't explain myself why this is. If you look at the circuit it doesn't matter where you insert the energy into the circuit, because the electricity you insert is everywhere in the circuit and so are the losses.

What am i missing?

Comment: Yes that's why you increase local generation. The electric grid is fundamentally constrained by the distance between the generator and the load (i.e. a natural monopoly). You would agree that transmission over a longer distance will incur more loss...right? Thats why people are talking about distributed networks rather than central networks and moving towards smaller, more flexible generators such as CHP, SCGT, wind and solar farms rather than coal plant, nuclear or hydro plants

Comment: yes i would agree that transmission over a longer distance will incur more loss. But the distance is always the same because the electricity will regardless travel through the whole network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "whole" electricity will not travel through the whole network.

First of all, on a big network, the common physical quantity if the frequency. The voltage is also shared, but may fluctuate locally (geographic viewpoint) depending on reactive power consumption/production.

However, even if the voltage is overall constant, you can draw the flux of energy going from power-plants to consumers (quite similar to current). The power flux doesn't go up to Portugal then come back to Germany. **The consumers take the power that is provided to them by the *network* which is himself fed by power-plants**. Of course, the consumed power will probably come from the closer power plants.

Now, if the network is balanced, and a consumer increases his consumption, you can in a first approximation consider that you add a new flux of energy to the network (superposition principle). Thus the closer the better.

In reality, it is much harder to tell. Big consumers in Denmark can buy electricity to a seller in Ukraine. Of course, there is no way for him to be sure to get the energy for the power-plants of the seller : he will use the energy available close to him, and the seller will fed the global network with the quantity of energy required. If a far away power plant increases his production, the global energy flux of the whole network will change so that local consumers will consume the energy available on their local network. If the increase of production is in Spain, it is false to assume that the power flux will go straight from Spain to the German consumer.

Moreover, the saturation of some power lines makes the problem even more complicated.

Comment: why is the flux of energy losing energy when traveling over a larger distance? so the network can be seen as a consumer which is everywhere?

Comment: @user3613886 Just because of classical ohmic losses. No, I wouldn't say that. The network is more like a marketplace.

Comment: so you say: example if you got a battery and a 500m long conductor to a resistance and a 1500m conductor back to battery. than this causes less energy loss than the same setting with both times 1000m conductors? i don't understand that?? energy losses have to be all over the network

Comment: @user3613886 In the European network, the cables are mainly three-phase, and the inward and outward currents travel trough the same line. In large networks, you **must** think in terms of energy flow.
If your battery is linked with 2 resistances in parallel, do you think that the currents flowing through the closest one will contribute to the ohmic losses in the cables between the two resistances ?

Comment: if all consumer and producer are parallel i would agree. Is this the case? If now the a local resistance is increased (consumer) then energy from the local producer increases the current intensity on the shortest path to the producer. while a far away producer would increase the current intensity for a long way so leading to more losses.

Comment: @user3613886 when you connect something on the network, do you assume that the network sets the voltage or the current ? Then is it like a parallel setting or series setting ?

Comment: from my understand is when i connect something to the network the voltage drops and then the producer has to increase the voltage again to stay consistent and as a by product the current increases, that would mean everybody is parallel

Comment: @user3613886 Yes, the network is usually seen as a strong voltage source. Every consumer shares the voltage (sometimes different voltages due to transformers and voltage level).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in the first place, this is not really a trivial topic, it's an entire subtopic of electrical engineering.

But in this case it should suffice to say, that in ordinary conductors, you have resistive losses, they're not ideal. You can find that the entire resistance of a grid element is proportional to the inverse of its cross-section and to its length. Therefore, if the provided energy has to flow over very long distances, the resistivity increases, and your resistive losses increase proportionally.

In the direct example of Germany you cite, you can observe this in their efforts to minimise these losses, i.e. the HVDC-lines that are planned to transport larger power flows from the coastal offshore wind farms to the south of Germany.

Comment: you describe what loss is, but in a circuit the current is flowing in a circle. Therefore wether the consumer is near or far the electricity has to flow through the hole grid and therefore the resistance is the same if the power plan is near or far